# Excess Pressure on a curved surface with two radius of curvature

Tags: pressure, curvature, fluid-statics, surface-tension

While studying surface tension, I noticed the following formula to calculate excess pressure on a curved liquid film made use of two radii of curvature:

$$2T\left(\frac{1}{R_{1}} + \frac{1}{R_{2}}\right)$$

I have not been able to understand the significance of two radii of curvature for a surface.

Comment: See these images of [lens](https://www.google.com/search?q=lens+with+two+radius+of+curvature&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIyYixjsPvAhVS4zgGHZKWAAEQ_AUoAXoECA4QAw&biw=1536&bih=762).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to visualize two different radii for any given surface. The best way is to cut the surface by a pair of perpendicular planes. Since, now you are viewing the section of surface cut by a plane you will have a planar surface which has a radius of curvature.

Try this out:::: Use a torus to apply the above argument. That will clear your doubt.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You can accept and upvote the answer if that satisfied your query.