# What is the excess pressure in a surface having 2 different radius of curvature?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

How is the excess pressure calculated in a surface if it consists of 2 different radius of curvatures ?

Comment: [Young–Laplace equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young–Laplace_equation).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In fluid mechanics we find out the excess pressure due to bubble or a droplet which have equal radius of curvature which makes it easier to calculate it .. what would be the excess pressure in a surface which has 2 different radius of curvature

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excess Pressure on a curved surface with two radius of curvature](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/622759/excess-pressure-on-a-curved-surface-with-two-radius-of-curvature) and also[Which are the radii of curvature in the Laplace Pressure formula?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609080/which-are-the-radii-of-curvature-in-the-laplace-pressure-formula)

Comment: $$P=\frac{\sigma}{R_1}+\frac{\sigma}{R_2}$$where the R's are the principal radii of curvature.

Comment: actually i am well acquainted with the formula but i am moreover interested in its derivation if you could just explain it to me how it came that'd be really helpful